# Constant in Regge trajectory

Tags: string-theory, mass, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force

The Regge trajectory in QCD is given by

$$m=\sqrt{\frac{J}{\alpha}-\alpha_0},$$

where $m$ is the mass and $J$ is the angular momentum of the hadrons, $\alpha=(4\pi\sigma)^{-1}$ is the inverse QCD string coupling and $\alpha_0$ is a constant.

Is the theoretical origin and an analytical expression for $\alpha_0$ known, or is it just an experimentally obtained input parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in this publication: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0309075v2.pdf

The mass formula is given by

\begin{equation}
m = \sqrt{\frac{2m_1m_2}{\alpha}J+(m_1^2 + m_2^2)},
\end{equation}

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the partons, $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant and $J$ is the angular momentum of the hadron.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0309075